# automatic prettier for python code? (as in javascript)

Tags: python, javascript

https://github.com/prettier/prettier-emacs does formatting for javascript

wonder if there's an equivalent for python code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Python has a lot of PEP regulations, one can use [`Black`](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) as their code formatter. This is found in the `Elpy` package or can be found on [github](https://github.com/pythonic-emacs/blacken).

Comment: darn, a lot of stars on in.. Thanks!

Comment: There is an emacs library that will automatically run black as well.